# write multiple table attributes as a class CSS

Tags: css, css-tables

I have this CSS:

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th 
{
padding: 3px;
}
```

How do I consolodate this in a class?
Something like this?:

```
.MY_TABLE table>tbody>tr>td, .MY_TABLE table>tbody>tr>th, .MY_TABLE table>tfoot>tr>td, .MY_TABLE table>tfoot>tr>th, .MY_TABLE table>thead>tr>td, .MY_TABLE table>thead>tr>th 
{
padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: `.table` is already a class. If you want a selector that’s equivalent except for specificity, that’s `.table th, .table td`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already have`.table` as class, so if you need to be more specific join the 2 classes (or add a parent) depending on your markup

```css
.table.MY_TABLE>tbody>tr>td,
.table.MY_TABLE>tbody>tr>th,
.table.MY_TABLE>tfoot>tr>td,
.table.MY_TABLE>tfoot>tr>th,
.table.MY_TABLE>thead>tr>td,
.table.MY_TABLE>thead>tr>th {
  padding: 3px;
}
```